# Overriding gcc's linker using binutil's ld

Tags: gcc, linker, gnu, ld, gcc9

We're using GNU gcc 9.2 on Solaris 10 - we got it preconfigured from a third party. Our problem is the linker - we want to replace it with a more recent version from binutils 2.23 but this is not so easy to do. Gcc's current config:

```
Configured with: ../configure 
--prefix=/usr/local/gcc9 
--with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld
--with-as=/usr/local/bin/as
--without-gnu-ld
```

As expected, gcc confirms the above info when asked where `ld` resides:

```
>> gcc -print-prog-name=ld
/usr/ccs/bin/ld
```

The linker we *want* to use is installed in a non-standard folder at `/home/chip/binutils223/bin`. Based on our research, gcc distributions with preconfigured tools are effectively *locked* and difficult to change. I suppose the tight integration between the compiler and various linkers/assemblers is the reason for this.

**-specs=[file]**

The only potential solution we found for changing the linker uses custom *specs* file to override gcc config parameters. We ran `gcc -dumpspecs`, it's quite noisy so we're only showing config parameters related to the linker:

```
>> gcc -dumpspecs
*linker:
collect2

*md_exec_prefix:
/usr/ccs/bin/
```

To be frank, the *specs* format is very strange and might as well be written in ancient hieroglyphics. Anyway, `md_exec_prefix` appears to hold the folder location where `ld` resides, so we wrote a custom specs file (myspecs.txt) to override it:

```
*md_exec_prefix:
/home/chip/binutils223/bin/
```

We then ran gcc with custom `myspecs.txt` ...

```
>> gcc -v simple.o -o simple -specs=myspecs.txt
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from myspecs.txt
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=...
Target: sparc-sun-solaris2.10
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc9 --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld
...
/usr/ccs/bin/ld -V -Y P,/lib:/usr/lib -Qy -o simple /home/...
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.10-1.1522
```

Gcc is definitely reading the specs file, but unfortunately it's still using the legacy `ld` at `/usr/ccs/bin/ld`. Is this strategy worth pursuing, or is it a dead-end? Are there other alternatives?

Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 1):

We settled on the following solution; it's a hack but we had no other solutions because of the way gcc searches[1] for the linker when configured with `--with-ld` option:

> The program `collect2` is installed as `ld` in the directory where the
> passes of the compiler are installed. When `collect2` needs to find
> the real `ld`, it tries the following file names:
>
> - a hard coded linker file name, if GCC was configured with the `--with-ld` option.
> - `real-ld` in the directories listed in the compiler’s search directories.
> - `real-ld` in the directories listed in the environment variable PATH.
> - The file specified in the `REAL_LD_FILE_NAME` configuration macro, if specified.
> - `ld` in the compiler’s search directories, except that `collect2` will not execute itself recursively.
> - `ld` in PATH.

So that means the first search path in the list always triggers for our gcc built with `--with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld`, and no standard option to override that behavior exists.

**Solution**

We symlinked `collect2` to reference bintutil's `ld`. Based on preliminary testing this solution works for our needs. The following command was executed in the folder where gcc `collect2` resides, for us that location was `gcc9/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/9.2.0`

```
ln -s /home/chip/binutils/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ld collect2
```

[1] - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html